# Is there a more intelligent sql-preprocessor for Oracle than Pro*C/C++?

Tags: c++, sql, c, oracle, oracle-pro-c

Does someone know if there is pre-processor for **C**/C++ in conjunction with Oracle that would allow me to write **C** or C++ code similar to:

```
void populateTableList(GuiList* tableList) {

     for users in ( select table_name, 
                           owner, 
                           tablespace_name
                      from dba_tables) 
     {
         tableList -> addRow(
                         users.table_name, 
                         users.owner, 
                         users.tablespace_name);
     }
 }
```

The main features I am looking for are

- quasi-automatic declaration/definition of the selected values (here: `users.table_name`, `users.owner` and `users.tablespace_name`) similar to the `PL/SQL for loop statement` and
- an automatic *fetch until finished* mechanism (without explicitely calling a `stmt.fetch()` procedure or something) and
- a validation of the correctnes of the sql statement at compile time.

Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

According to the following 9, 10, 11 pages there is no other C/C++ 
"precompiler" other than PRO*C/C++.  There is a C/C++ programming 
language interface  called OCI/OCCI, but technically this is not a precompiler

This page states that "OCI programs are not precompiled":

```
http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Oracle_Call_Interfaces
```

These pages list the available C/C++ compiler tools:

9I precompiler page:
    http://docs.oracle.com/html/A97297_01/ch4_comp.htm

```
This page lists PRO*C/C++, 
and the Non C precompilers: PRO*COBOL, PRO*FORTRAN,
SQL for ADA, the OCI
```

10G precompiler page: See part number B25416-02
    (This page Does not list any other C/C++ precompilers not
    already listed)

9I to 11 precompiler notes:
    https://blogs.oracle.com/db/entry/master_note_for_precompilers_oci_and_occi

```
(This page Does not list any other C/C++ precompilers not
already listed)
```

Ask Tom OCI/PRO*C comparison:
    http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:999630650601

```
This page shows an example that has an SQL statement with
invalid syntax being passed to OCI, through OCIStmtPrepare()
and the compile does not error.  This means that 
at the time of the OCI compile a complete syntax check
of the SQL statement is not done which is 
consistent with what I have seen.
```

This page states "OCI and Precompilers Support for (..)" implying 
that OCI does not do precompilation:

```
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/oci/index.html
```

It looks like the code you have has SQL embedded in it.  To check
this code for validity at compile time would require a precompiler
that has access to the data dictionary (I know PRO*C does, with
a different syntax that what you have  but none of the other ORACLE
supported tools  for C/C++ listed on the above pages do).

Comment: There may be 3rd party tools, but I could not find any, and with 3rd party tools you always run the risk that the 3rd party tool does not completely support an ORACLE specific SQL construct - there have been so many new syntax changes/additions to PLSQL especially in 10/11